# How to break the Query parameter values into key value pairs in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

My requirement is I will get all the query parameters in a variable called **q**. I want to break that into a key-value pair and store it in a map.

Ex: http:////getResource?q=Name='Test', age=18, dob='dd-mm-yyyy'

Want to have a central logic which will convert the query parameter **q** into key-value pairs.

Like :
Name:Test
age:18
dob:dd-mm-yyyy

Is there any API which will solve this. All Rest URLs should go through that API and if any value is available for **q** variable then I want to delimit that with "=" and store in hashmap as key-value pair.

Thanks, Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you :-

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)

```
public String testUrl(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) 
{   
  (...)
}
```